# Sort ListView not working with custom adapter and with many data in a single item

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview, adapter

I'm struggling sorting my listview using custom adapter. I've been looking for solutions here but I can't seems to find the right solution for my problem. Here is my code.

```
adapter = new ResultListAdapter(this, temList, politicianName, lastName, platform, candidatePosition, votes, image);
    listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.candidate_listView);


    Collections.sort(votes, StringDescComparator);
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);


    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static Comparator<String> StringDescComparator = new Comparator<String>() {

    public int compare(String vote1, String vote2) {

        String stringName1 = vote1;
        String stringName2 = vote2;

        return stringName2.compareToIgnoreCase(stringName1);
    }
};
```

This is the normal view of my list:

[Normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjqRq.png)

[And this is my result of my code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mJYM.png)

As you can see in the image the **Votes** are the only one that is sorted and not the other data.
Does anyone know what to change or to add in my code?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: your ``votes`` list is of type ``String`` ?

Comment: Yes.. it is easier for me to make it as String. I think it is not based on my variable type.

Comment: What is ``temList`` ? I think you should sort something else, not your votes. I mean the entire entity that is in your listView

Comment: `temList` is the party name.. hmm if I sort the entire entity it would result in a scrambled data in each item in the list based on my sorting..

Comment: "Votes are the only one that is sorted and not the other data. "  That's want you want, isn't it ? To sort other data as well, or I'm not getting something?

Comment: + you should pass in your adapter a single list with people for example. it's bad coding if you pass all the data from your list sepatatelly.

Comment: you're right but what I'm trying to figure out is that to sort all the data in the item based on a single comparator like **Votes** ? And then the other data on that item should sort according to the sorted **Votes**. is that possible?

Comment: Nope, you will lose the order. You can to keep the data linked when you sort

Comment: Thanks.. I'll just need to change something in my adapter. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator seems to sort list of Strings. I think that you want to sort Candidates that  might be in temList ? Change comparator to compare Candidates by their Votes. But your adapter has  problems also  It should adapt Candidate as whole not as separate lists of attributes that are sorted separately. That is the main  reason for the mixup of candidate data, if i  guessed  right.

Comment: Exactly.. the main reason for the mixed up of my list is in my adapter. I better change it as a whole list instead. Thanks!